# Scrape patents.google with Scrapy fails

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the main title of this page: https://patents.google.com/patent/CN102093389B/en ("Duplex and oxygen bridge heterlcyclic ring anabasine compound and preparation method thereof") with Scrapy and it is not possible. I am trying extract it with css. The same css selector in puppeteer works fine and extract the main header but in Scrapy gives None. The code  have written is this

```
import scrapy

class GooglepatentsspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'googlePatentsSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['patents.google.com']
    start_urls = ['https://patents.google.com/patent/CN102093389B/en']

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.css('h1#title::text').get()

        yield {
            'title': title
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css path is incorrect. Try this,  `response.css('span[itemprop="title"]::text').get()`

Comment: Yes this is woriking but where did you find a span element with itemprop attribute? I am looking the html page and I can't find in h1 something like this. What am I missing?

Comment: if you check the page source you will find it easily. Moroever, what you see while inspecting does not guarantee you will get the same HTML while making  requests. Please, accept the answer if it helped you.